# where Should i put async await, on class js or nuxt html?

Tags: javascript, async-await, nuxt.js

**classWooCommerceProducts.js**

```
import {
    WooComRestApi
} from "~/plugins/classWooCommerceOrigin.js";

export class WooCommerceProducts {
    constructor() {

    }

//-- A method --
async get() {
    const getproducts = await WooComRestApi.get("products").then((response) => {
        return response.data
    }).catch((error) => {
        return "WooCommerceProducts get failre"
    })

    return getproducts
}

//or

//-- B method --    
    get() {
    const getproducts = WooComRestApi.get("products").then((response) => {
        return response.data
    }).catch((error) => {
        return "WooCommerceProducts get failre"
    })

    return getproducts
}
}
```

**products.vue**

```
   // -- A method --
        methods: {
            getProducts() {
                const WooComProducts = new WooCommerceProducts()
                WooComProducts.get().then((response) => {
                    this.products = response
                }).catch((error) => {
                    throw new Error(error)
                })
            }
        },

or
   // -- B method --
        methods: {
            async getProducts() {
                const WooComProducts = new WooCommerceProducts()
                await WooComProducts.get().then((response) => {
                    this.products = response
                }).catch((error) => {
                    throw new Error(error)
                })
            }
        },
```

guys a quick question on two part

1. i have a js class is calling from backend and get back products data, both code works, one is i async and await on the html vue the other one is i async await on the js class, so which one did right ? can anyone tell me what different dose it make ?
2. how do i return the data or the error back to the function getProducts and result same return as the class. if fail return "wooCommerceProducts : get failure" and it will return back to my getProducts catch error functions.

learning more  greatful for sharing your advice. How will you implete if was you ?

Answer (score 0):

The thing to remember is that `async/await` is just more modern syntax for promise `.then()`.  It doesn't make sense to mix them.

> how do i return the data or the error back to the function getProducts

Return the data explicitly in the async syntax (inside a `try/catch`).  In the older promise style, return the promise.

```
//-- A method --
async get() {  // note that no "then" appears here
  try {
    const response = await WooComRestApi.get("products");
    return response.data;  // note the return
  } catch(err) {
    console.log("WooCommerceProducts failure");
    throw err;
  }
}

//or, using the older syntax

//-- B method --    
get() {
  return WooComRestApi.get("products").then((response) => {  // note the return
    return response.data;
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log("WooCommerceProducts get failure");
    throw error;
  });
}
```

> i have a js class is calling from backend and get back products data, both code works, one is i async and await on the html vue the other one is i async await on the js class, so which one did right ?

Same pattern as before "A method" is correct because it doesn't need a return. For "B method", you've chosen the new style, so stick with it...

```
// -- B method --
methods: {
  async getProducts() {
    const WooComProducts = new WooCommerceProducts()
    try {
     this.products = await WooComProducts.get();
    } catch(error) {
      // handle error
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: so what you mean is using async await in try catch is new way then using then() and put async await with then() will make no sense at all. so i should use async await on both class js and inside the vue but remove the then() if i want to use async await. did i get it right ?

Comment: i am using using both with async await with try catch now, i console.log out the return data and it have a object call promise and my page wont should any data, only if i switch the vue part to using then() the data show. is there a way to show the data using try catch ?